# Palidrome checker in haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, palindrome

I decided to avoid the trivial `isPalindrome lst = lst == reverse lst` and tried writing a method with pattern matching and recursion.

```
allButFirstAndLast :: [a] -> [a]
allButFirstAndLast = tail . init

isPalidrome :: [a] -> Bool
isPalidrome [] = True
isPalindrome [a] = True
isPalindrome [a,b] = a == b
isPalindrome lst = (isPalindrome (allButFirstAndLast lst)) &&
                   ((head lst) == (last lst))
```

Comment: IMO it's seldom a good idea to *avoid trivial* solutions as long as there isn't something forcing you to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The implementation is correct, but not efficient. The problem are the calls to `last` and `init`, which are both *O(n)*, which makes the whole function *O(n^2)*. On the other hand, `lst == reverse lst` is just *O(n)*.

See [Finding palindromes in a linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7049210/1333025).

Also the pattern

```
isPalindrome [a,b] = a == b
```

is redundant, you can omit it and let it be handled by the generic case.

Comment: You could maintain start and end indices to avoid the n^2 issue; but that would compromise on elegance.